# Access to exposed header from Angular 8

Tags: angular, http-headers

Im trying to get the exposed header from the backend with angular 8. here you can see the Response headers when I Posted the API

```
**Response headers(6)**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Xtoken, CX-Token, Content-Disposition
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 09:03:34 GMT
Vary: Origin
```

I want to access to **Xtoken**.

```
login(login: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${apiUrl.apiUrl}//login`, { login, password }, { observe: 'response' as 'body' })
            .pipe(map((res, err) => {
                console.log(res.headers.get("Xtoken"));

            }));
    }
```

It return **null**.

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Is there a key in your header called "Xtoken"?

Comment: @NikNik yes there's a key called "Xtoken"

Comment: In your header example, it's missing